# Random MySQL connectivity issues?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, connection, digital-ocean

I can run the exact same command over and over again and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't:

```
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.245.54.251' (115)
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
#mysql50#lost+found
busman
demo_busman
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
#mysql50#lost+found
busman
demo_busman
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
#mysql50#lost+found
busman
demo_busman
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
#mysql50#lost+found
busman
demo_busman
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
#mysql50#lost+found
busman
demo_busman
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
#mysql50#lost+found
busman
demo_busman
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.245.54.251' (115)
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.245.54.251' (115)
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.245.54.251' (115)
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.245.54.251' (115)
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
#mysql50#lost+found
busman
demo_busman
information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
root@bak-rrk9m:/# mysql -Bsuroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h"$KMB_MARIADB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST" -e "show databases"
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.245.54.251' (115)
```

My website, OTOH, doesn't seem to be getting any errors.

What's going on? How do I fix this?

It's the same issue whether I use the hostname or internal/cluster IP address.

---

Got some logs from the MariaDB pod. This might be it:

> 2020-06-15  0:51:51 12069 [Warning] Aborted connection 12069 to db: 'demo_kmbookings' user: 'root' host: '10.244.0.84' (Got an error writing communication packets)

---

Found [some article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/) with some suggestions but nothing concreate.

Thought maybe it was running out of RAM while creating those dumps since I cheaped out and only gave it 1 GiB or so. Fortunately Kubernetes made it easy to rebuild my whole cluster on a bigger node, but that didn't help.

Noticed now that my MariaDB service `selector` didn't actually match my deploy template. I fixed that and now it's running successfully. Will have to try a few more times to be sure, but it makes me wonder how this ever worked.

Comment: Well, 115? that's an odd "should never happen" sort of error. You tagged this kubernetes. Can you provide your pod definition? e.g. `kubectl get pod my-pod -o yaml` Is your cluster running ok? See [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/) for troubleshooting.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Here's my backup pod: https://mpen.xyz/share/2020/06/2020-06-14_17-54-30.txt My cluster seems fine. I have a website running on the cluster connected to the same DB, and I haven't noticed any errors with it. I added an error for the mariadb pod to the question.

Comment: Nice of them to not actually mention what the error was!

Comment: Did you notice any pod restarts on your mariadb pods? That would explain intermittent connectivity issues since you have `replicas: 1`; also, FWIW, it's dangerous to use `Deployment` with a stateful Pod -- that's why `StatefulSet` exists and is used for databases

Comment: @mdaniel No, didn't notice and restarts. MariaDB pod is reporting 0 restarts. Is `Deployment` dangerous even when the data is in a PV?

Comment: There are some subtle differences between Deployments and StatefulSets, but the biggest differences are that if you try to scale the Deployment to 2 replicas, it will never work because only one Pod can have _that PV_ at a time, and if you try to change the image or environment variable in your Deployment, it will create a ReplicaSet which will never start because the new Pods also cannot bind to _that PV_

Comment: @mdaniel Interesting. I figured 1 replica and strategy=Recreate were just limitations I needed to keep. Will have to try out StatefulSet. Thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this was a Kubernetes configuration issue. My MariaDB deployment looked like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mariadb-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: b437e465-2526-41bb-ae19-534b3a60f2eb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod: b437e465-2526-41bb-ae19-534b3a60f2eb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mariadb
          image: mariadb
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: mariadb-env
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mariadb-volume
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/zzz-kymark.cnf
              subPath: my.cnf
      volumes:
        - name: mariadb-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mariadb-pvc
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: mariadb-config
```

But my service definition looked like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mariadb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: kymark-mariadb-pod
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
```

Notice the `selector` doesn't match.

I haven't studied up on how that all works yet, but I assume if the service selector doesn't match the pod definition, then Kubernetes doesn't know how to set up the network properly.

What I don't get is why it would still work *sometimes*. Where was Kubernetes routing all the traffic to? Why did my website still work?

I guess the lessons here are:

1. Check the logs for your *database*. The client error doesn't contain much information.
2. Double-check your Kubernetes config and selectors

There were no errors to suggest my config was wrong, but here we are.

Answer (score 0):

The **selector** used in service spec must match with the deployment spec, otherwise your service won't redirect the traffic for the correct pod.

Is common some people use the same selector for various application inside the cluster in the beggining because they don't understand how it works.

I've extracted some points from [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment):

> The .spec.selector field defines how the Deployment finds which Pods to manage. In this case, you simply select a label that is defined in the Pod template (app: nginx). However, more sophisticated selection rules are possible, as long as the Pod template itself satisfies the rule.

> Note: You must specify an appropriate selector and Pod template labels in a Deployment (in this case, app: nginx). Do not overlap labels or selectors with other controllers (including other Deployments and StatefulSets). Kubernetes doesn't stop you from overlapping, and if multiple controllers have overlapping selectors those controllers might conflict and behave unexpectedly.

Comment: @mpen Does this answer your questions ?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a similar mistake. I copy pasted the contents from a a different pod (database server) to use for a yaml template where they almost share the same specs and config, but I forgot to change the app label which resulted in random 2002 (HY000) ... (115)

Took me a while to figure out nothing was wrong at the database server side, but rather the wrong app label applied for the pod with mysql-client.
The randomness totally took me off guard.